# Adding business information to an overlay in a MapView

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay

On the Google maps web interface if you zoom in enough you can see businesses that are clickable. When you click the business you get the a speach bubble with a brief description of the business.

Even on the native android Google map you can tap businesses and get a link to the business information.

My question is that within a MapView is it possible to add my own overlay that when tapped loads the business info of a pre existant business? Is it possible to associate my overlay with a business in some way. I imagine that I could do this if I duplicated the html found on the google map in some way into my overlay, but I was hoping to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I have used this. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons Not sure how to pull info though.

Comment: I can vouch for android-mapviewballoons. I've used it for one of my projects and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that within a MapView is it possible to add my own overlay that when tapped loads the business info of a pre existant business?

Assuming you find a source for the data, sure.

> I imagine that I could do this if I duplicated the html found on the google map in some way into my overlay, but I was hoping to avoid this.

I highly doubt that will work.

First, you must find a Web service or something that has the data you seek. Then, you need to license that data. Then, you need to figure out how you want to render that data on the map overlay. The first two of those steps are the tricky ones.

Comment: Is is possible to get this data from Google? Via search perhaps?